# Using QtWidgets in a Qt HTML5 Application

Tags: c++, html, qt

I am in the process of developing a HTML5 Application using the Qt Framework.  I am a little bit confused as to how it works.  I know Qt has Widgets, like QTableWidget, QPushButton, etc.

Would I use those widgets for laying out my application? How can I use lets say a QPushButton in my application.  Or is everything suppose to be CSS, HTML, Javascript, and I would use C++ for backend stuff like Networking, text processing, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The qt html5 application work is that you set up an html5 viewer widget (something like a web browser) and you use html5 for your UI and you can interface it c++ with websockets to call your binaries written in c++, or you can create server-side application which evaluates requests from browser and returns html5 as response. this article might help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336018/Building-C-Applications-with-HTML5. 
So to answer your questions, No you can't use QPushButton and Qt widgets in your html5 view. and yes, everything is supposed to be in CSS, HTML, and javascript and c++ is used as a backend